# How to expand a PPM Image in Java using RGB arrays

Tags: java, arrays, image, netbeans, ppm

I am working on a java project (creating my own image editior) and my task is to allow the user to double the size of a existing PPM image. I must do this through the use of 2-d arrays of RGB. My instructor gave me a hint that I must create a new image with double the width and height of the first one and new arrays to fill it. I believe I've done this correctly. However, when I run my program and click the double size button on my interface, my original image doubles in size, but it becomes completely black. I believe there is a problem with how I am transposing the RGB values. I inserted print statements to see when the code goes wrong( when my RGB values become zeros)....

```
else if (action.equals(doubleSizeMenuItem.getActionCommand())) {
    int gimmieRows = thePPMImage.getNumRows();
    int gimmieCols = thePPMImage.getNumCols();
    int[][] gimmieRed = thePPMImage.getRedPixels();
    int[][] gimmieBlue = thePPMImage.getBluePixels();
    int[][] gimmieGreen = thePPMImage.getGreenPixels();
    int[][] doubleMyRedPixels = new int[gimmieRed.length * 2][gimmieRed.length * 2];
    int[][] doubleMyBluePixels = new int[gimmieBlue.length * 2][gimmieBlue.length * 2];
    int[][] doubleMyGreenPixels = new int[gimmieGreen.length * 2][gimmieGreen.length * 2];
    int longer = gimmieRows * 2;
    int wider = gimmieCols * 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < longer; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < wider; j++) {
            doubleMyRedPixels[i * 2][j * 2]=gimmieRed[i][j];
            doubleMyRedPixels[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieRed[i][j];
            doubleMyRedPixels[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2]= gimmieRed[i][j];
            doubleMyRedPixels[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieRed[i][j];
            doubleMyGreenPixels[i * 2][j * 2]=gimmieGreen[i][j];
            doubleMyGreenPixels[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieGreen[i][j];
            doubleMyGreenPixels[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2]= gimmieGreen[i][j];
            doubleMyGreenPixels[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieGreen[i][j];
            System.out.println(doubleMyRedPixels[0][0]);
            doubleMyBluePixels[i * 2][j * 2]=gimmieBlue[i][j];
            doubleMyBluePixels[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieBlue[i][j];
            doubleMyBluePixels[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2]= gimmieBlue[i][j];
            doubleMyBluePixels[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieBlue[i][j];

            thePPMImage=new PPMImage(doubleMyRedPixels, doubleMyGreenPixels, doubleMyBluePixels);
            System.out.println(doubleMyRedPixels[5][5]);
            thePPMImage.setRedPixels(doubleMyRedPixels);
            thePPMImage.setGreenPixels(doubleMyGreenPixels);
            thePPMImage.setBluePixels(doubleMyBluePixels);
            System.out.println(doubleMyRedPixels[2][7]);
            imageLabel.setIcon( new SImage(
                transposeArray(thePPMImage.getRedPixels()),
                transposeArray(thePPMImage.getGreenPixels()),
                transposeArray(thePPMImage.getBluePixels())));
                System.out.println(doubleMyRedPixels[4][6]);
```

It appears that the image becomes black once i hit this line.

```
thePPMImage=new PPMImage(doubleMyRedPixels, doubleMyGreenPixels, doubleMyBluePixels);
System.out.println(doubleMyRedPixels[5][5]);
```

Ok so I've tried the following codes, ***separately*** in my nested for loop and I receive an ArrayOutOfBounds exception for each of them.My understanding of it is that if i have a pixel at (5,3) and I want to double it, I need it to be transposed and doubled in width and in height taking up 4 places. (10,6) upper left (10,7) upper right, (11,6) bottom left, (11,7) bottom right. so I need 4 assignment statements for each r g and b right?

IDK
I've tried the following  four as the contents of my nested for loop without any luck.

```
              //1st try


             doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[i/2][j/2];
             doubleMyGreenPixels[i ][j]=gimmieGreen[i/2][j/2];
             doubleMyBluePixels[i ][j]=gimmieBlue[i/2][j/2];

              //2nd try
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[i/2][j/2];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[i / 2][(j / 2) - 1];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[(i / 2) - 1][j /2];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[(i / 2) - 1][(j /2) - 1];

              doubleMyGreenPixels[i ][j]=gimmieGreen[i/2][j/2];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[i / 2][(j / 2) - 1];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[(i / 2) -1][j / 2];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[(i / 2) -1][(j / 2) - 1];

              doubleMyBluePixels[i ][j]=gimmieBlue[i/2][j/2];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i][j]=gimmieBlue[i /2][(j / 2) - 1];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i][j]=gimmieBlue[(i / 2) - 1][j / 2];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i][j]=gimmieBlue[(i / 2) -1][(j / 2) - 1];*/
              //3rd try
              doubleMyRedPixels[i ][j]=gimmieRed[i*2][j*2];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i][j]=gimmieRed[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1];

              doubleMyGreenPixels[i ][j]=gimmieGreen[i*2][j*2];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1];

              doubleMyBluePixels[i ][j]=gimmieBlue[i*2][j*2];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i][j]=gimmieBlue[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i][j]=gimmieBlue[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i][j]=gimmieBlue[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1];

              //4th try
              doubleMyRedPixels[i * 2][j * 2]=gimmieRed[i][j];
              doubleMyRedPixels[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieRed[i][j];
              doubleMyRedPixels[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2]= gimmieRed[i][j];
              doubleMyRedPixels[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieRed[i][j];

              doubleMyGreenPixels[i * 2][j * 2]=gimmieGreen[i][j];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieGreen[i][j];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2]= gimmieGreen[i][j];
              doubleMyGreenPixels[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieGreen[i][j];

              doubleMyBluePixels[i * 2][j * 2]=gimmieBlue[i][j];
              doubleMyBluePixels[i * 2][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieBlue[i][j];
              doubleMyBluePixels[(i * 2) + 1][j * 2]= gimmieBlue[i][j];
              doubleMyBluePixels[(i * 2) + 1][(j * 2) + 1]= gimmieBlue[i][j];
```

Ok so I think I got it.

My new 2D int arrays should have been initialized like this.

```
        int[][] doubleMyRedPixels = new int[gimmieRed.length * 2][gimmieRed[0].length * 2];
        int[][] doubleMyBluePixels = new int[gimmieBlue.length * 2][gimmieBlue [0].length * 2];
        int[][] doubleMyGreenPixels = new int[gimmieGreen.length * 2][gimmieGreen[0].length * 2];
```

and my for loops should be as follows;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < longer; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; **j** < wider; j++) {
```

and the aforementioned **1st try** allows me to double the size of any ppm image!

Comment: Divide the indexes by two on the right side rather than multiply by two on the left. eg doubleMyRedPixels[i ][j ]=gimmieRed[i/2][j/2] and move the new PPMImage code to after the end  of the for loop rather than inside the for loop.

Comment: @WillShackleford Thanks for your speedy response! I basically undid the operation like you said and put it onto the left. I also put the "new image" code outside of the for loop ,but now i get an array out of bounds exception. The image wont even double anymore. It wont turn black either...

Comment: @Will The inside of my for loop looks like this:
                    
                     doubleMyGreenPixels[i ][j]=gimmieGreen[i/2][j/2];
                    doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[i / 2][(j / 2) - 1];
                    doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[(i / 2) -1][j / 2];
                    doubleMyGreenPixels[i][j]=gimmieGreen[(i / 2) -1][(j / 2) - 1];

Comment: It is better to edit the original question than to put code in the comment. That way it can be properly formatted. You don't need any of the lines with -1 added to the indexes. Use only the first line.

Comment: @Will .My understanding of it is that if i have a pixel at (5,3) and I want to double it, I need it to be transposed and doubled in width and in height taking up 4 places. (10,6) upper left (10,7) upper right, (11,6) bottom left, (11,7) bottom right. so I need 4 assignment statements for each r g and b right? I updated the question this time with my different attempts. none of them seem to be working.

Comment: You don't need 4 assignments , four different combinations of i,j will be set from the same value of i/2,j/2 eg  (i=2,j=2),(i=3,j=2),(i=2,j=3) and (i=3,j=3) all  set from the pixel at 1,1 in the original image. The first try is correct. If it is still not working there must be another problem somewhere else.

Comment: @Will Wow. thanks so much. I figured it out. I'm not sure why my professor said i had to do four statements for each. Your technique worked exactly. My problem was that in my second for loop, I was using the index i again instead of j. I also needed to amend the length of my new int array. I was assuming that the length of the rows always equals the length of the columns which is rarely true for any image. That's why I was receiving the ArrayOutOfBoundsException- I was running out of space. Anyway thanks so much. I Appreciate the insight!